# Db migration fails with: Error: Cannot find module './typeorm'

Tags: typescript, postgresql, typeorm

Using:

```
❯ node --version
v16.19.0

❯ yarn --version
3.5.0
```

I am trying to get this project up and running:

https://github.com/felipebelinassi/typescript-graphql-boilerplate

but when I get to:

```
yarn db:migrate
```

which is running:

```
ts-node typeorm migrations:generate -n
```

it fails with:

```
❯ yarn db:migrate

node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:998
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module './typeorm'
Require stack:
- /Users/test/repos/typescript-graphql-boilerplate/imaginaryUncacheableRequireResolveScript
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:995:15)
    at Function.resolve (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:109:19)
    at requireResolveNonCached (/Users/test/repos/typescript-graphql-boilerplate/node_modules/ts-node/dist/bin.js:549:16)
    at getProjectSearchDir (/Users/test/repos/typescript-graphql-boilerplate/node_modules/ts-node/dist/bin.js:519:40)
    at phase3 (/Users/test/repos/typescript-graphql-boilerplate/node_modules/ts-node/dist/bin.js:267:27)
    at bootstrap (/Users/test/repos/typescript-graphql-boilerplate/node_modules/ts-node/dist/bin.js:47:30)
    at main (/Users/test/repos/typescript-graphql-boilerplate/node_modules/ts-node/dist/bin.js:33:12)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/test/repos/typescript-graphql-boilerplate/node_modules/ts-node/dist/bin.js:579:5)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1165:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1219:10) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/Users/test/repos/typescript-graphql-boilerplate/imaginaryUncacheableRequireResolveScript'
  ]
}
```

**package.json**:

```
{
  "name": "typescript-graphql-boilerplate",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "license": "ISC",
  "description": "Simple TypeScript and GraphQL project boilerplate",
  "author": "Felipe Belinassi",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "prebuild": "del-cli --force ./build",
    "build": "tsc",
    "prestart": "yarn build",
    "start": "node -r dotenv/config build/app.js",
    "start:dev": "ts-node-dev --transpile-only -r dotenv/config src/app.ts",
    "test": "jest --projects ./tests/integration --runInBand",
    "db:migrate": "ts-node typeorm migrations:generate -n"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "apollo-server-express": "^2.24.0",
    "apollo-server-testing": "^2.24.0",
    "class-validator": "^0.13.1",
    "dotenv": "^9.0.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "graphql": "^15.5.0",
    "joi": "^17.4.0",
    "pg": "^8.11.3",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "type-graphql": "^1.1.1",
    "typedi": "^0.8.0",
    "typeorm": "^0.3.16",
    "typeorm-typedi-extensions": "^0.4.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.17.11",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.23",
    "@types/node": "^15.0.2",
    "del-cli": "^3.0.1",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "ts-jest": "^26.5.6",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "ts-node-dev": "^2.0.0",
    "typescript": "^5.2.2"
  }
}
```

any ideas on how to fix the issue - and postgres is running via docker-compose?

I tried to upgrade dependencies, I expected the db to get populated with data. It fails and seems to be related to typeorm.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use DataSource instead ormconfig. It was [deprecated](https://typeorm.io/changelog#deprecations).

Example of DataSource file:

```js
import "reflect-metadata";
import { DataSource } from "typeorm";
import { Client } from "./entity/Client";

import { migration1661206795941 } from "./migration/1661206795941-migration";

const entities = [Client]

const migrations = [
  migration1661206795941
];

export const AppDataSource = new DataSource({
  type: "postgres",
  host: "localhost",
  port: 5434,
  username: "postgres",
  password: "postgres@2020",
  database: "postgres",
  synchronize: false,
  logging: false,
  entities: entities,
  subscribers: [],
  migrations: migrations,
});
```

And change your db: migrate script to:

```
db:migrate: typeorm migration:generate path/to/Migration -d path/to/datasource
```

Just for the record in case anyone comes up with this error message:
This specific error message is because use ts-node to handle with the migrations. Ts-node is trying to find typeorm in its modules:

"db:migrate": "`ts-node` typeorm migrations:generate -n"